# Socket not throwing exception when not connecting

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception

```
    executor.submit(() -> {
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
        return null;
    }).get();
```

As the code is now, if I try to input lets say letters or something in the ip I get an exception, but if I choose an existing local IP the program just freezes at the .get(). I'm guessing that it's just sitting there wait for a connection from that ip/port, is there any way for me to have it timeout so that if there's no listening computer it throws an exception?

Comment: FYI the reason it's in an excecutor is because Java apparently now requires all socket openings to be in a different thread, but I don't want my program continuing until it's opened.